# JS Registration Form

Tags: javascript, html, registration

I am creating a registration form with a name a email and a phone number. I have a name id a phone id and a email id also I have txtNameError, txtPhoneError, and txtEmailError and I am using a bnt button id.

Here is the HTML for the program.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Week 12: Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" placeholder="Name" /></td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtNameError">Name must be at least 6 characters long.</p>
 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Phone: ###-###-
 ####" /></td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtPhoneError">Phone must be in the format ###-###-####.</p>
 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email Address" />
 </td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtEmailError">Must be a valid email address.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><button id="btnRegister" 
 name="btnRegister">Register</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="week12.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="week12.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
    var txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    var txtPhone = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
    var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName');
    var txtEmailError = document.getElementById('txtEmailError');
    var txtPhoneError = document.getElementById('txtPhoneError');
    var txtNameError = document.getElementById('txtNameError');




    function register(){

    if (/^[A-Z \.\-']{6,20}$/i.test(txtName.value)) {
    p.error {display:none;}
    } else {
    p.error {display:txtNameError;}
    }
    if (/\d{3}[ \-\.]?\d{3}[ \-\.]?\d{4}/.test(txtPhone.value)) {
    p.error {display:none;}
    } else {
    p.error {display:txtPhoneError;}
    }
    if (/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,99}$/.test(txtEmail.value)) {
    p.error {display:none;}
    } else {
    p.error {display:txtEmailError;}
    }
    }
    {
    var btnRegister = document.getElementById('btnRegister');
    btnRegister.onclick = register;
    }
```

I'm using Modern javascript develop and design which was written by larry ullman.

I'm not sure though on how I am suppose to get the txterrors to work before I had a style.visibility in the html which I could set the if and else statement and if it was true I could make it hid or vis or if false hid or vis. I'm not sure on how to do this though I did read about addErrorMessage() and removeErrorMessage() functions which I would add the id and the error message but I am not sure what that means though since in the html file I was provided the Error msg are in the html file. Thanks For any tips.

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

.page {
margin: 10px auto;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background: #CCC;
}

.page table {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.error {
color: #FF0000;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tips [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-sample-registration-form-validation.php)

Comment: that's a pretty good tip but it's using alert() functions. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use in one place

> var txtPhone = U.$('phone');

and in other

> var txtNameError = document.getElementById('txtNameError');

I think this is copy and paste and you don't understand how it work. 
And in your html not exists fields with name or id "phone".

In first you should use one method for access to HTML elements.

```
var txtPhone = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
```

2. This code is very strange too:

> if (/^[A-Z .-']{2,20}$/i.test(txtName.value.length > 6))

For check length you should make check it separate or change regexp.

```
if (/^[A-Z \.\-']{7,20}$/i.test(txtName.value))
```

3. For hidden errors text you can use CSS. For example,

   p.error {display:none;}
4. For show error you should make error message visible

   if (/^[A-Z .-']{7,20}$/i.test(txtName.value)) {
     //value is correct. make some if need
   } else {
     //value is wrong
     //show element txtNameError
   }